# How to upload data by chunks to Azure Blob Storage using PHP

Tags: php, stream, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the [Azure Storage Client for PHP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php)

I would like to be able to stream data chunk by chunk, to reduce the memory overhead associated with reading the entire file into memory. I have looked through the library docs, but I haven't found anything that would help.

At the moment I use `fopen()`, but as far as I'm aware it reads the entire file into memory. Would it be possible to do something along the lines of:

```
while ($data = fread($file, 8192)) {
    //some library function
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to do so. The methods you would want to use are [`createBlobBlock`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/2930b735ad0157e398cc54ec89dee138b8efd3f0/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L2462) (or [`createBlobBlockAsync`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/2930b735ad0157e398cc54ec89dee138b8efd3f0/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L2498) and [`commitBlobBlocks`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/2930b735ad0157e398cc54ec89dee138b8efd3f0/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L2747) (or [`commitBlobBlocksAsync`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/2930b735ad0157e398cc54ec89dee138b8efd3f0/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L2781)).

Essentially the idea is that you read some chunk of data from the source and upload that chunk (known as `block` in Azure Storage). For that you would use either `createBlobBlock` or `createBlobBlockAsync`. Each block must be assigned a unique id.

Once all blocks are uploaded, you would commit the blocks to create the block. To commit the blocks, you would use either `commitBlobBlocks` or `commitBlobBlocksAsync`.

For more details, please see these two links: [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Put-Block) and [`Put Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list)