# Download large file in PHP from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: php, azure, blob, storage

I'm in the process of migrating a website offering large downloadable files (4GB and up) into Azure. I have successfully created the connection to the Azure storage account so I can retrieve the files. However the download a) takes ages to start and b) consumes loads of memory since I read the entire file into memory before actually sending the downloadable data to the client.
Is there a way to read the file in chunks from the Storage account to avoid the delay and memory consumption?
The current code looks like this:

```
$getBlobResult = $blobClient->getBlob($containerName,$FileName);
$blobProperties=($getBlobResult->getProperties());
$FileSize=$blobProperties->getContentLength();
// Send headers 
header ("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header ("Content-Length: $FileSize");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$FileName\"");
// Send content of file
echo stream_get_contents($getBlobResult->getContentStream());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving the file to the user via a signed URL as @CodeBrauer suggests would be the most preferable solution since you don't have to pipe the data through your code/infrastructure at all.

Though if that is at odds with your requirements, then you can try replacing:

```php
echo stream_get_contents($getBlobResult->getContentStream());
```

With:

```php
fpassthru($getBlobResult->getContentStream());
```

Which should just dump the stream straight out without needing virtually any buffer.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru

Comment: fPassThru works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

For many reasons, I would recommend just serving the download directly from the storage. Mostly, because you have a big I/O performance impact and your traffic is also heavily loaded.

Instead of using PHP I would suggest the following solutions - depending on what your hosting environment allows you to do.

- Serve a URL of the file directly (using [shared access signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) if a public URL is not an option)
- If you don't want to redirect the user to an azure link, download the file to your server with something like [`azcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download), rename it to some `<hash>.<ext>` and serve the direct URL to the user.
- If you really need/want to use PHP, you can work through how to split a file and stream it to the user: [How to upload data by chunks to Azure Blob Storage using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185978/how-to-upload-data-by-chunks-to-azure-blob-storage-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to read the file in chunks from the Storage account to
> avoid the delay and memory consumption?

You can certainly do that. When downloading blob using [`getBlob`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/2930b735ad0157e398cc54ec89dee138b8efd3f0/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L3703) method, you will need to specify the byte range you wish to download in the `options` parameter which is of type [`GetBlobOptions`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/2930b735ad0157e398cc54ec89dee138b8efd3f0/azure-storage-blob/src/Blob/Models/GetBlobOptions.php).

If I am not mistaken, you would need to define the range in `start-end` format (e.g. `0-1023` to download 1KB)